# Sending a file through FTP to a share-drive (UNC)

Tags: vba, excel, ftp, unc

I have a particular file which needs to be sent to a share drive location through FTP.

I know there is a method by writing contents on a flat file and executing with shell script. Sadly that is not working since my send location is weird and I don't know how to interpret it, its like this.

```
//corporate.abc.com/data/ac/ny/log
```

I have no idea what the above thing means. Is there any way to send data to that location?

PS: I opened it through my Windows *Run* command and its opening up. It is not asking for any user authentication.

Update: I tried to open using explorer but I am getting error" runtime  error 75 , path/file access error"

```
Sub FtpFileto() 
Dim vFile As String
Dim vFTPServ As String
Dim fNum As Long
vPath = "C:\macro/pop.txt"
vFile = "C:\macro/post.xlsx"
vFTPServ = "corporate.abc.com" 
Open "//corporate.abc.com/data/NA/US/OC/Common/HOSTDL/CatSpec" For Output As #1
Close
Shell "ftp -n -i -g -s:" & vPath & "\FtpComm.txt " & vFTPServ, vbNormalNoFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: If you copy-paste that to the Windows Explorer address bar what happens?  That looks like a regular UNC path - perhaps you're missing the "ftp:" part?

Comment: "ftp to share drive"? Huh? unc paths have nothing to do with FTP...

Comment: @TimWilliams IT just opens up.. nothing unusual.. I want to FTP to it

Comment: @MarcB What is UNC paths?

Comment: `//server/share` is a unc path

Comment: a UNC path is like a regular file path - you likely do not need to use FTP to place a file there - just save as to that location, copy/paste the file or use regular VBA methods to copy a file.

Comment: Oh.. How do I do that..? It has a .com in the middle so I thought I need to ftp

Comment: How do you do what exactly?  It's not clear exactly what you want to do.  Where is this file you want to place in that location, and exactly how are you wanting to send it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the UNC path can be opened in Windows Explorer, it means that it is directly accessible and can be worked with as if it were a local path.

```
Open "\\corporate.abc.com\data\ac\ny\log\test.ext" For Output As #1
Write #1, Data
Close #1
```

You do not need (cannot) use FTP to work with it.

---

Note that the UNC is a Windows convention, so it uses backslashes, not forward slashes (though in many cases Windows will accept the forward slashes too).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but when i use your code i am getting runtime error 75. Path file access error

Comment: Is the `CatSpec` a file or folder? Did you try using backslashes?

Comment: Yeah , its working, but not through your method, I simply put "SAVE AS "address" and it worked . Thanks for the idea of saving without ftp , kindly edit your answer and i will accept it :-)

Comment: What is "Save as address"?

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="//corporate.abc.com/ac/af/test.xls"

Comment: You use a different path every time. That makes it difficult to help you. But I assume that the `log` is a directory name, so you should have used `Open "\\corporate.abc.com\data\ac\ny\log\test.ext" For Output As #1`.